# MySQL GROUP BY - Select column matching aggregate function (without join)?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I've written the following SQL query against MySQL's good old [`world`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/) database:

```
SELECT Continent, Region, Name, MAX(SurfaceArea) 
FROM world.country 
GROUP BY Continent, Region;
```

The `country` table looks something like this:

```
| Code  | Name          | Continent | Region                      | SurfaceArea | ...
| 'AFG' | 'Afghanistan' | 'Asia'    | 'Southern and Central Asia' | 652090.00   |
| 'ALB' | 'Albania'     | 'Europe'  | 'Southern Europe'           |'28748.00'   |
...
```

My query above works in MySQL InnoDb v5.7.26 and emits the correct `MAX(SurfaceArea)` per `Continent` and `Region`. However, the `Name` emitted is incorrect, in that it is not the name of the country with the most surface area.

For example, note the `United Arab Emirates` row here:

```
| Continent | Region         | Name                   | MAX(SurfaceArea) |
| 'Asia'    | 'Eastern Asia' | 'China'                | '9572900.00'     |
| 'Asia'    | 'Middle East'  | 'United Arab Emirates' | '2149690.00'     |
...
```

This is because selecting a non-aggregate, non-literal column that is not part of the `GROUP BY` clause does not make much sense. I believe MySQL just arbitrarily defaults to the first value it encounters in the group.

**My question is** - How can I write the above query correctly, preferably without using a `JOIN`?

That is, return a table with the `Name` and the `SurfaceArea` of the country with the `MAX(SurfaceArea)` per each `Continent` and `Region`.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow for linking to an almost identical question with answers. This answer is pretty much what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745679/33404

Comment: it's great to see that someone finally appreciates a duplicate closure as help and does not take it as a personal insult!